# Conventions over Configuration with Caliburn.Micro and code obfuscation in .NET

Tags: .net, obfuscation, caliburn.micro, convention-over-configur

We're considering using [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) and Conventions over Configuration for our application, but I'm concerned that code obfuscation (which we require for the distributed application) will interfere with the naming conventions. Without having actually tried this, I reckon I must add a set of exceptions to avoid classes/namespaces/fields/functions from being renamed to enable the conventions.

What is your experience doing obfuscation with Caliburn.Micro (or other similar frameworks)? Are there alternative approaches to using naming conventions that work better in an obfuscated context (e.g. creating a manual map of types to do the mapping)?

We're using [Crypto Obfuscator for .Net](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) for obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried several solutions for the obfuscation problem in WPF but no matter what application or framework i use i couldn't get the job done because of the binding system and the heavy reliance WPF has on names (be that class names, property names, you name it) so i will suggest not to burden your self with this unless it is an absolute requirement.